# Remove the password from Microsoft Access file

Tags: microsoft-access

I have an mdb file on my computer, but unfortunately I have forgotten my password, so I can not open it now.

Is there any way to remove this password or some other way to open this file?

Comment: What version of Access?

Comment: Database passwords are almost completely useless, so once you've removed it, don't put one back.

Comment: @DavidW.Fenton: that's a bit of a silly thing to say. They will stop novice users from opening up an MDB and messing it up. They do serve a valid purpose.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[Access PassView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/accesspv.html)

> This utility reveals the database password of every password-protected mdb file that created with **Microsoft Access 95/97/2000/XP or with Jet Database Engine 3.0/4.0** . It can be very useful if you forgot your Access Database password and you want to recover it.

Comment: The best!!! Worked like charm

Answer (score 4):

for old versions of Access I've had luck with this:
http://jackcess.sourceforge.net/

```
import com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.*;  

Database db=Database.open(new File("xxxx.mdb"));  
System.out.println(db.getDatabasePassword() );
```